# iPhone/Cocoa: NSPredicate regex replace?

Tags: iphone, regex, cocoa

According to [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9), I can use NSPredicate to do regex matching on strings, i.e., the perl equivalent of `$my_string =~ m/[some regex]/`

But can I do regex replace, i.e. the equivalent of this perl expression: `$my_string =~ s/[pattern]/[replacement]/g` ?

Answer (score 9):

[Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) has some useful regex functionality. It works on the iPhone. Take a look at [GTMRegex.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMRegex.h). There is a category on NSString with this method:

```
- (NSString *)gtm_stringByReplacingMatchesOfPattern:(NSString *)pattern withReplacement:(NSString *)replacementPattern;
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution I've found is RegexKitLite:

http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/

(Note the "Lite" version is the one you use for the iPhone)

Just two files to add to a project, and a -licucore flag for the linker.  It uses the built in regex abilities.

It has NSString extensions, including ones to do replacements and can also pull out multiple matches by number.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is not available natively in Cocoa, but you can use the standard c regex.h functions as described [here](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/87) (about three quarters of the way down the page).

There is also an open source library called [ObjPCRE](http://mohrt.blogspot.com/2009/03/perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html) which may do the trick.

And someone was able to make it work [using JavascriptCore](http://parmanoir.com/Cocoa_Regular_Expressions_via_JavascriptCore).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4.0+ and Mac OS X 10.7+, you can use `NSRegularExpression`