# Replace a substring with another substring

Tags: objective-c, string, replace, nsstring

I want to replace the string "abc" to "def" each time it appears in my NSString object:
"axcd abc amamam dff abc kdj abc"

How do I do that??

Thanks,

Sagiftw

Comment: For future reference, spaces between tags represents different tags.  I've fixed it for you, but the proper objective C tag is "objective-c".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.

```
NSString* foo = @"axvc abc amamam dff abc kjd abc";
NSString* bar = [foo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"abc" withString:@"def"];
NSLog("%@", bar);
```

Comment: @KaranAlangat, are you sure about that? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:) says that it's still  available and not deprecated, both in the iOS sets and OS X sets.

Comment: @zneak It s a mistake from me. I did check in my Xcode a lot of time and it didn't work for me. Now a days my Xcode shows unwanted errors even in blank lines. It works fine .

Answer (score 2):

Check out [replacing regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760902/iphone-cocoa-nspredicate-regex-replace)